# Ubuntu losing video after boot?

Tags: video

Ubuntu newb here but I'm quite stuck.  I recently downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.3 and burned a DVD, then appeared to get a successful install on a freshly formatted 1tb WD HD.  Gui interface and stock software all seemed fine at first, web access via Firefox as expected then after about a half hour ... my screen goes dark. The hard drive seems to be continuing to read and write.  At first I assumed my video card had died, but cutting the power then booting on my Win7 HD the video works fine.  This is on about a 6 year old asus p6t deluxe v 2 mboard w/i7 and 6mb ram, and a run of the mill ATI video card.

I don't think this is solely a hardware issue as first, the computer and video run fine when I reinstall my old Win7 drive. Secondly, problem is getting worse as I now get just a blank purple screen before it goes black. I have no speakers on the computer.

Any suggestions regarding where to head first will be appreciated.  I do know I'm looking at reinstalling Ubuntu at the least, but I'd prefer to avoid simply reproducing my error(s).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it just when you are running videos or simply when a half hour is up? It may be a setting but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings. My hunch is that is simply goes black after 30 minutes of inactivity. Next to the orange suitcase(software center) There should be a wrench with a wheel. Click on this. There should be a wide selection of setting options. on the very top, you should see this screenshot:

[image: settings1]

Double click on this and it will open open up to this:

[image: settings2]

Click the drop down menu on the top and select "never" if you do not ever wish for the computer to lock up after 30 minutes of inactivity. I hope this helps.